# ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [OPTIONS] "/admin_login")

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, axios

My frontend is react backend is rails.

I got the error.

But it seems routing is right.

Why it got the error...

`react(View)`

```
export default function LoginPage() {
  const theme = createTheme();

  const [email, setEmail] = useState<string>("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState<string>("");

  const authenticatingAdminUser = async () => {

    await axios
      .post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_ENDPOINT}/admin_login`, {
      //REACT_APP_ENDPOINT is http://localhost:3000
        params: {
          email: email,
          password: password,
        },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log("エラーです", e);
      });
  };

  return (
        ...
            <TextField
              ...
              value={email}
              onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            />
            <TextField
              ...
              value={password}
              onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
            />
            <Button
              ...
              onClick={authenticatingAdminUser}
            >
              ログイン
            </Button>
      </Container>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

rails(routing)

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  post '/admin_login' => 'sessions#login'
end
```

`error`

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [OPTIONS] "/admin_login"):
```

When I try get request, it was success.

Only post requst would fail.

I really don't know why.

I searched on google, there was nothing to help me.

Please help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed CORS setting for rails...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).